# Change UIToolbar Button Image from Code

Tags: objective-c, xcode

is there any way to change the button image inside UIToolbar?

I am actually using this way but it doesn't work.

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"]];
```

For your information, "myButton" is an IBOulet UIBarButtonItem.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *myButton;
```

Comment: hey you just drag the UIButton in the xib itself ....

Answer (score 2):

Use the following cole. i hope it will use to you.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );    
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:myTarget action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Thanks,.

Comment: Er, for your information, it is a UIBarButton, does it works like a UIButton?

Answer (score 1):

//  add images to bar button item of toolbar in iphone

to set button type as custum:

```
button=[UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

// add the image on toolbar:

```
 [toolbar insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc]
                         initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:1];
```